# .flv and .f4v file extensions displaying unexpected mime type

Tags: php, mime-types, flv

When I look up the mime types of my `.flv` and `f4v` in `php` it states them as: application/octet-stream.

I always thought the mime types for these files were 'video/x-flv' and 'video/x-f4v'. Is this a new thing or are the files coming from a funky source or something?

Comment: In php? Care to share that code? detecting MIME types can often be unreliable, for example I use [winista and if that fails I resort back URLMon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8736109/495455). Sounds like the code your using defaults back to a octet stream...

Comment: thaks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734832/determining-mime-type-of-mac-upload-stream-file/8736109#8736109) that both Winista and URLMon dont detect swf's or flv's properly. This is why the php component you're using cant fully identify the 'video/x-flv' and 'video/x-f4v' files.

Winista uses a **magic** file (that contains a list of MIME types and respective hex chars that indicate the starting bits of particular files).

I suggest you focus on why no-one else has been able to add flv detection to this magic file. The winista project to is a port from an old Java open source project.

The only other thought I have is trying ffmpeg, maybe it has the smarts to detect the exact MIME Type of these flv and f4v files.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) on board my PHP 5.4.7 (in XAMPP under Windows) is able to detect `.flv` file as `video/x-flv`, but fails on `.mkv` video (should detect it as `video/x-matroska`, but returns `application/octet-stream` instead) and many other non-typical multimedia formats.

To solve this problem I dropped FileInfo at all and reverted back to old, good *mime-by-extension* method, using following function:

```
public static function getMimeTypeByExtension($file)
{
    $extensions = require('mimeTypes.php');

    if(($ext=pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))!=='')
    {
        $ext=strtolower($ext);
        if(isset($extensions[$ext]))
            return $extensions[$ext];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Contents of `mimeTypes.php` you can find at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/pxwA9gFh). It is compiled by me, by merging [Apache SVN's `mime.types` file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=annotate) and similar [`mimeTypes.php`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/utils/mimeTypes.php) array from Yii Framework. Resulting set has over 1000 relations between file extension and coresponding MIME-type.

**Importan note**: Before using this solution, you must carefully consider, what purpose you need it for? MIME-type based on file extension can be very easily spoofed, by simply changing that extension. So any security-related piece of code should be kept **far as possible from my solution**.

I needed it only for simple purpose of providing correct MIME-type of video file for [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/docs/). I assumed that, if user change extension of such file to something else, then flowplayer will simply fail to playback that movie.